# Metro plastic card Valencia

Tags: trains, public-transport, valencia

On a trip in 2015 I bought a plastic card for the metro in Valencia, Spain.
It seems to be a Móbilis Card as shown here:

[image]

Are these still in use and will my card still be working on my trip next week?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are still in use according to the EMT website

https://movil.emtvalencia.es/ciudadano/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=133&Itemid=68&lang=en

However the Spanish version is slightly more informative and suggests they expire after 5 years. That may just mean you lose any stored values and can recharge it or that may not even be possible.

https://movil.emtvalencia.es/ciudadano/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=133&Itemid=68&lang=es

> En nuestras Oficinas de Atención al Cliente: Plaza del Correo Viejo nº 5 en días laborables de 9h00 a 19h30 y en los puntos de información ubicados en la estación de Metro Colón  de 9 a 19H de lunes a viernes y en UPV, de 8 a 15:30H (periodos lectivos)

So you need to go to Palza del Correo Viejo on a weekday from 0900 to 1930 or the Metro station Colon or UPV whatever that is to get advice.

> Llamándonos al 96 315 85 15 en días laborables de 8h00 a 21h00 y sábados de 9h00 a 14h00.

Or you can ring that number and hope they speak English